# How to authenticate with LDAP email or mobile instead of username?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

### How to authenticate with LDAP `email` or `mobile` instead of `username`?

In a Spring boot 1.5.9 application, I am using `spring-security-ldap` and I use the default `LdapUserDetailsManager` class to login.

It use the `loadUserByUsername` method by default.

I have two types of users:

- Back-Office: should be able login with `username` (or at the worst case, email)
- Customers: should be able to login with `mobile`, `email`

This is the content of `org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsManager`:

```java
public class LdapUserDetailsManager implements UserDetailsManager {
    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(LdapUserDetailsManager.class);

    /**
     * The strategy for mapping usernames to LDAP distinguished names. This will be used
     * when building DNs for creating new users etc.
     */
    LdapUsernameToDnMapper usernameMapper = new DefaultLdapUsernameToDnMapper("cn=users",
            "uid");

    /** The DN under which groups are stored */
    private DistinguishedName groupSearchBase = new DistinguishedName("cn=groups");

    /** Password attribute name */
    private String passwordAttributeName = "userPassword";

    /** The attribute which corresponds to the role name of a group. */
    private String groupRoleAttributeName = "cn";
    /** The attribute which contains members of a group */
    private String groupMemberAttributeName = "uniquemember";

    private final String rolePrefix = "ROLE_";

    /** The pattern to be used for the user search. {0} is the user's DN */
    private String groupSearchFilter = "(uniquemember={0})";
    /**
     * The strategy used to create a UserDetails object from the LDAP context, username
     * and list of authorities. This should be set to match the required UserDetails
     * implementation.
     */
    private UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsMapper = new InetOrgPersonContextMapper();

    private final LdapTemplate template;

    /** Default context mapper used to create a set of roles from a list of attributes */
    private AttributesMapper roleMapper = new AttributesMapper() {

        public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws NamingException {
            Attribute roleAttr = attributes.get(groupRoleAttributeName);

            NamingEnumeration<?> ne = roleAttr.getAll();
            // assert ne.hasMore();
            Object group = ne.next();
            String role = group.toString();

            return new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rolePrefix + role.toUpperCase());
        }
    };

    private String[] attributesToRetrieve;

    public LdapUserDetailsManager(ContextSource contextSource) {
        template = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        DistinguishedName dn = usernameMapper.buildDn(username);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthorities(dn, username);

        logger.debug("Loading user '" + username + "' with DN '" + dn + "'");

        DirContextAdapter userCtx = loadUserAsContext(dn, username);

        return userDetailsMapper.mapUserFromContext(userCtx, username, authorities);
    }

    private DirContextAdapter loadUserAsContext(final DistinguishedName dn,
            final String username) {
        return (DirContextAdapter) template.executeReadOnly(new ContextExecutor() {
            public Object executeWithContext(DirContext ctx) throws NamingException {
                try {
                    Attributes attrs = ctx.getAttributes(dn, attributesToRetrieve);
                    return new DirContextAdapter(attrs, LdapUtils.getFullDn(dn, ctx));
                }
                catch (NameNotFoundException notFound) {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                            "User " + username + " not found", notFound);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Changes the password for the current user. The username is obtained from the
     * security context.
     * <p>
     * If the old password is supplied, the update will be made by rebinding as the user,
     * thus modifying the password using the user's permissions. If
     * <code>oldPassword</code> is null, the update will be attempted using a standard
     * read/write context supplied by the context source.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param oldPassword the old password
     * @param newPassword the new value of the password.
     */
    public void changePassword(final String oldPassword, final String newPassword) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();
        Assert.notNull(
                authentication,
                "No authentication object found in security context. Can't change current user's password!");

        String username = authentication.getName();

        logger.debug("Changing password for user '" + username);

        final DistinguishedName dn = usernameMapper.buildDn(username);
        final ModificationItem[] passwordChange = new ModificationItem[] { new ModificationItem(
                DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute(passwordAttributeName,
                        newPassword)) };

        if (oldPassword == null) {
            template.modifyAttributes(dn, passwordChange);
            return;
        }

        template.executeReadWrite(new ContextExecutor() {

            public Object executeWithContext(DirContext dirCtx) throws NamingException {
                LdapContext ctx = (LdapContext) dirCtx;
                ctx.removeFromEnvironment("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool");
                ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,
                        LdapUtils.getFullDn(dn, ctx).toString());
                ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, oldPassword);
                // TODO: reconnect doesn't appear to actually change the credentials
                try {
                    ctx.reconnect(null);
                }
                catch (javax.naming.AuthenticationException e) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException(
                            "Authentication for password change failed.");
                }

                ctx.modifyAttributes(dn, passwordChange);

                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param dn the distinguished name of the entry - may be either relative to the base
     * context or a complete DN including the name of the context (either is supported).
     * @param username the user whose roles are required.
     * @return the granted authorities returned by the group search
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthorities(final DistinguishedName dn,
            final String username) {
        SearchExecutor se = new SearchExecutor() {
            public NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> executeSearch(DirContext ctx)
                    throws NamingException {
                DistinguishedName fullDn = LdapUtils.getFullDn(dn, ctx);
                SearchControls ctrls = new SearchControls();
                ctrls.setReturningAttributes(new String[] { groupRoleAttributeName });

                return ctx.search(groupSearchBase, groupSearchFilter, new String[] {
                        fullDn.toUrl(), username }, ctrls);
            }
        };

        AttributesMapperCallbackHandler roleCollector = new AttributesMapperCallbackHandler(
                roleMapper);

        template.search(se, roleCollector);
        return roleCollector.getList();
    }

    public void createUser(UserDetails user) {
        DirContextAdapter ctx = new DirContextAdapter();
        copyToContext(user, ctx);
        DistinguishedName dn = usernameMapper.buildDn(user.getUsername());

        logger.debug("Creating new user '" + user.getUsername() + "' with DN '" + dn
                + "'");

        template.bind(dn, ctx, null);

        // Check for any existing authorities which might be set for this DN and remove
        // them
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthorities(dn, user.getUsername());

        if (authorities.size() > 0) {
            removeAuthorities(dn, authorities);
        }

        addAuthorities(dn, user.getAuthorities());
    }

    public void updateUser(UserDetails user) {
        DistinguishedName dn = usernameMapper.buildDn(user.getUsername());

        logger.debug("Updating user '" + user.getUsername() + "' with DN '" + dn + "'");

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthorities(dn, user.getUsername());

        DirContextAdapter ctx = loadUserAsContext(dn, user.getUsername());
        ctx.setUpdateMode(true);
        copyToContext(user, ctx);

        // Remove the objectclass attribute from the list of mods (if present).
        List<ModificationItem> mods = new LinkedList<ModificationItem>(Arrays.asList(ctx
                .getModificationItems()));
        ListIterator<ModificationItem> modIt = mods.listIterator();

        while (modIt.hasNext()) {
            ModificationItem mod = (ModificationItem) modIt.next();
            Attribute a = mod.getAttribute();
            if ("objectclass".equalsIgnoreCase(a.getID())) {
                modIt.remove();
            }
        }

        template.modifyAttributes(dn, mods.toArray(new ModificationItem[mods.size()]));

        // template.rebind(dn, ctx, null);
        // Remove the old authorities and replace them with the new one
        removeAuthorities(dn, authorities);
        addAuthorities(dn, user.getAuthorities());
    }

    public void deleteUser(String username) {
        DistinguishedName dn = usernameMapper.buildDn(username);
        removeAuthorities(dn, getUserAuthorities(dn, username));
        template.unbind(dn);
    }

    public boolean userExists(String username) {
        DistinguishedName dn = usernameMapper.buildDn(username);

        try {
            Object obj = template.lookup(dn);
            if (obj instanceof Context) {
                LdapUtils.closeContext((Context) obj);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a DN from a group name.
     *
     * @param group the name of the group
     * @return the DN of the corresponding group, including the groupSearchBase
     */
    protected DistinguishedName buildGroupDn(String group) {
        DistinguishedName dn = new DistinguishedName(groupSearchBase);
        dn.add(groupRoleAttributeName, group.toLowerCase());

        return dn;
    }

    protected void copyToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {
        userDetailsMapper.mapUserToContext(user, ctx);
    }

    protected void addAuthorities(DistinguishedName userDn,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        modifyAuthorities(userDn, authorities, DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE);
    }

    protected void removeAuthorities(DistinguishedName userDn,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        modifyAuthorities(userDn, authorities, DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE);
    }

    private void modifyAuthorities(final DistinguishedName userDn,
            final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, final int modType) {
        template.executeReadWrite(new ContextExecutor() {
            public Object executeWithContext(DirContext ctx) throws NamingException {
                for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
                    String group = convertAuthorityToGroup(authority);
                    DistinguishedName fullDn = LdapUtils.getFullDn(userDn, ctx);
                    ModificationItem addGroup = new ModificationItem(modType,
                            new BasicAttribute(groupMemberAttributeName, fullDn.toUrl()));

                    ctx.modifyAttributes(buildGroupDn(group),
                            new ModificationItem[] { addGroup });
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    private String convertAuthorityToGroup(GrantedAuthority authority) {
        String group = authority.getAuthority();

        if (group.startsWith(rolePrefix)) {
            group = group.substring(rolePrefix.length());
        }

        return group;
    }

    public void setUsernameMapper(LdapUsernameToDnMapper usernameMapper) {
        this.usernameMapper = usernameMapper;
    }

    public void setPasswordAttributeName(String passwordAttributeName) {
        this.passwordAttributeName = passwordAttributeName;
    }

    public void setGroupSearchBase(String groupSearchBase) {
        this.groupSearchBase = new DistinguishedName(groupSearchBase);
    }

    public void setGroupRoleAttributeName(String groupRoleAttributeName) {
        this.groupRoleAttributeName = groupRoleAttributeName;
    }

    public void setAttributesToRetrieve(String[] attributesToRetrieve) {
        Assert.notNull(attributesToRetrieve, "attributesToRetrieve cannot be null");
        this.attributesToRetrieve = attributesToRetrieve;
    }

    public void setUserDetailsMapper(UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsMapper) {
        this.userDetailsMapper = userDetailsMapper;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name of the multi-valued attribute which holds the DNs of users who are
     * members of a group.
     * <p>
     * Usually this will be <tt>uniquemember</tt> (the default value) or <tt>member</tt>.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param groupMemberAttributeName the name of the attribute used to store group
     * members.
     */
    public void setGroupMemberAttributeName(String groupMemberAttributeName) {
        Assert.hasText(groupMemberAttributeName, "groupMemberAttributeName should have text");
        this.groupMemberAttributeName = groupMemberAttributeName;
        this.groupSearchFilter = "(" + groupMemberAttributeName + "={0})";
    }

    public void setRoleMapper(AttributesMapper roleMapper) {
        this.roleMapper = roleMapper;
    }
}
```

It use an `username` (ldap `uid`) to perform login.

I want to be able to login using the `mobile` phone number  or the `email` stored in LDAP.

### Version

- `spring-security-ldap`: `4.2.3.RELEASE`

### Question

- Is there a tutorial or someone who have already done that before?
- How can two login endpoints with differents criteria exists in Spring?

  - username
  - email or mobile

Comment: You want to make a custom `LdapUserDetailsMapper` and `LdapUserDetails`. Then you can use these in a class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment, I was feeling lonely. (nice nickname btw) How can I configure two login endpoint in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?  How can I have two controllers for such tasks? Why `LdapUserDetailsMapper` and `LdapUserDetails` ? By `LdapUserDetails`, do you mean `LdapUserDetailsManager` or is it a different think? If you have some example, I would take anything you can give me. Thanks a lot  again.

Comment: Misread the question, that would allow you add extra info to principle returned. It would also require you to be using `AuthenticationManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication()`. Personally I think it would probably be easiest to just create your own `UserDetailsService`,`AuthenticationToken` and `UserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points) for multiple entryPoints.

Comment: Thanks again @123, Do you also know where I can get resource for the customization of LDAP? I am used to directly map with a ldap search on attributes, now I understand what the mapper is, I just don't know how I can override method in it, most of the class is protected.

Comment: Not really, you can probably piece something together from posts on here + maybe sites like baeldung. If you have any issues with specific parts, then post questions on here. As it stands though I think this is a little too complex for a single question on SO. Wrt to the mapper, I just wrote my own that implemented `UserDetailsContextMapper`

Comment: I am stuck with the tutorial, it doesn't show how to use multiple `authenticationProvider`  and to use different service for authenticating, do you know if I can use multiple `@Bean` `DaoAuthenticationProvider` ?

Comment: What tutorial? I doubt you can use multiple beans of authentication providers. See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers) for one way

Comment: This tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points) for multiple  entrypoint. Is 123 the SO name for Baeldung?:)

Comment: Nah, just the first results that come up. Like I said I would just make my own with `UserDetailsService`, `AuthenticationToken` and `UserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`, then you could check whatever auths you wanted in there.